# Why response is None testing view using RequestFactory()?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, client

I am trying to test my view using RequestFactory(). However, calling this view in the test responded as None:

### View

```
def add_to_basket(request):
cart = Cart(request)
if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
    # GETS game DATA FROM AJAX REQUEST
    game_id = request.POST.get('gameId')
    game_qty = int(request.POST.get('gameQty'))
    # check if game exists
    try:
        game = Game.objects.get(pk=game_id)
    except Game.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Game not found'})
    # CHECKS IF ANY OPEN ORDER
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        #  CHECK IF GAME ALREADY ADDED
        order = order_qs[0]
        add_new_item_to_order(request,
                              game_qty,
                              game,
                              order)

    else:
        # create new order
        order = Order.objects.create()

        add_new_item_to_order(request,
                              game_qty,
                              game,
                              order)

    # ADDS GAME TO SESSION DICT
    actual_qty = order.items.get(item_id=game_id).quantity
    cart.add(game, actual_qty)
    # get total QTY of basket
    cart_length = cart.__len__()
    # message
    if game_qty != actual_qty:
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Item quantity was adjusted!', 'total': order.total, 'qty': cart_length, 'instock': False})
    elif game.quantity_available == 0:
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Item was added', 'total': order.total, 'qty': cart_length, 'instock': False})
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Item was added', 'total': order.total, 'qty': cart_length})
```

### Test setUp

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
    # request factory
    self.factory = RequestFactory()
    self.middleware = SessionMiddleware()
```

### Test itself

```
    def test_add_to_basket(self):
    # set sessions middleware
    request = self.factory.post(reverse('order:add-to-cart'))
    self.middleware.process_request(request)
    request.session.save()
    # request.user = self.test_user
    response = add_to_basket(request)

    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
```

Printing *response* outputs None - though apart test, view is working as expected. What could cause this?

Comment: I don't see you return anything when no exception is raised in that `try` block. Neither do you return anything if that `if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':` condition is `False`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , Thanks for reply. Sorry. I just didn't copy the rest of the view. **Edited** It is returning JSONRespnose in any case.

Answer (score 0):

okay. I got it.
I forgot to pass 'action' variable in post request
`request = self.factory.post(reverse('order:add-to-cart'))` -
**should be**:
`request = self.factory.post(reverse('order:add-to-cart'), data={'action': 'post', ...)`